# JavaScript Object not being correctly posted to backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In an attempt to **post** a JS object with jQuery 2.1.x to PHP 7.1 code, the PHP backend receives an empty object with the following code:

JS:

```js
$("#newTabLink").click(function(e) {
      ntn++;
      console.log('ntn = ' + ntn + ' / id =' + id);
      id++;
      var tabData = new Object();
      var tc = $('#tabs').children().length;
      console.log('tc = ' + tc)
      tabData.label = 'New Tab ' + ntn;
      tabData.pos = tc;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'services/save_obj.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(tabData),
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        encode: true,

        success: function(response) {
          if (response.success == true) {
            id = response.id;
          } else if (response.success == false) {
            alert('Aww, something went wrong!');
          }
        }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

services/save_obj.php :

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $strvalue = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'label', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'objsay', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $lang = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lng', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'loc', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $position = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pos', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Scratching my head to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing `data: JSON.stringify(tabData),` by `data: tabData,`

Comment: And use `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send from frontend application JSON data, you can find your data into php script, using php://input.

Example:

services/save_obj.php

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
if(!empty($input)){
   $input = json_decode($input, true);
   // ... some logic
}
```

You can use global $_POST, only with form-data.